# Creating simple polyline geometry objects with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point, line, array

I'm trying to learn how to create a polyline object from a set of XY pairs. I need to create an empty point object and an empty array object, place the coordinates in a list, and use a for loop to iterate through the list and populate the point object. From there I'm pretty sure I can create the polyline from the array, which is the last step.

How do I go from the list of points to the point object using a for loop? I've been trying to use the .add or .append functions to no avail.

```
# Import module
import arcpy

# Create empty objects:
#
# Point
point = arcpy.Point()
# Array
array = arcpy.Array()

# Create a list of coordinates (X, Y)
coordinates = [[260, 320], [450, 420], [360, 680], [600, 1000], [900, 190]]

# For loop iteration through coordinates
for pair in coordinates:
  point.x = pair[0]
  point.y = pair[1]

  # What else goes here to populate the point object?

print point # to test if loop is functioning correctly
```

Comment: It's wise to create and use a `SpatialReference` object in the `Polyline` constructor.

Comment: I appreciate that. This, however, is not going to be used for anything and I'm just trying to learn these concepts for a course.

Comment: Then why ask a question that is featured prominently in the documentation at all?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Code Sample in the Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm#C_GUID-FC2C3085-2C89-4CDB-985B-DFE78118B603) that appears to do this:

> **Polyline example**
>
> Create a polyline feature class from scratch.